# What is the relationship between a bundle identifer and a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on my first iOS project. I created my app in Xcode, and it works fine in the iPad simulator. Then I purchased an iPad and signed up and paid for the $99/year development program. I assumed it wouldn't be too hard to try the app out on my new iPad! Wrong!

I have now gone to through the provisioning portal process and generated/downloaded all the certificates and provisioning profiles. XCode has accepted a provisioning profile for my iPad. BUT when I build my project for the iPad target, the build fails because;
"A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.triplehappy.publish' could not be found".

I assigned com.triplehappy.publish as my Bundle Identifier before I got the provisioning profile. What is the bundle identifier and how can I link it to my provisioning profile ?

Edit: It turns out my bundle identifier and provisioning profile were compatible; I had a different problem (see San's answer and comments). For the record a simple bundle identifier like com.triplehappy.publish is compatible with a simple provisioning profile Application ID of the form QWERTYABC4.* I haven't yet had to deal with the more complex multiple product/multiple developers/app store ready scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Your provisioning profile have also bundle identifier. So your app should have the same bundle identifier as your provisioning which you are using.You can use developer provision profile to run any app directly on your device.

For more details concept take a look to apple's documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

Comment: Thanks. But looking at my provisioning profile it has Name, Platform, Creation, Expiration, App Identifer, Team and Status. No bundle identifier. I tried using the App Identifier from the profile as my "bundle identifier" but that failed with the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to build using iPhone Developer profile? What's your automatic profile selector in your Xcode it's showing? What's your error message?Can you show the screen shot of code signing sections?

Comment: Thanks, your answer and comments were helpful (upvoted). It was the code signing sections of the build settings that were a problem. The only personal profile I had was in the section "Identities without Provisioning Profiles". I quit Xcode, double clicked the previously downloaded mobile provisioning file, which took me to Xcode Organizer, then "refreshed" the profile and let Xcode talk to the authority. A new (I think) developer profile appeared out of this process and I was able to successfully link to it in the code signing sections.